# What is the best WSO2 upgrade strategy?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

What is the best / flexible WSO2 upgrade strategy?

Because now we are upgrading WSO2 DSS 3.0.1 to DSS 3.1.1, therefore there is some difficult changes in dbs file one by one

wso2dss-3.0.1

```
<data name="BASE_PERSON_DataService" serviceNamespace=
"http://company.mn/base/BASE_PERSON">
```

wso2dss-3.1.1

```
<data description="multiple services per each table" enableBatchRequests="false" 
enableBoxcarring="false" name="BASE_PERSON_DataService"
 serviceNamespace="http://company.mn/base/BASE_PERSON" serviceStatus="active">
```

What is the easy way, we have many data services (dbs files)?

Regards,
Eba

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is usually no standard migration tool or procedure available. Check that the newer version uses a compliant schema for the wso2 registry database and so on; maybe it's the same or you just need to create new additional tables. Sometimes you find things like migration scripts in the dbscripts folder. You should also check for differences in newer xml configuration files, and adjust your older custom configuration to the new format (usually few or no changes could be required). As far as the artifacts are concerned, I never heard of any way to convert them. If there are many of them, I would probably try some script and regex to batch modify and adjust them to the new format.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps you should follow if you are upgrading

Step 1 - Deploy artifacts {dbs/datasource/drivers}

Cappy the deployed data services from current installation to new installation by copying repository/deployment/server folder.(all dbs files are backword compatible so what ever worked in WSO2 DSS 3.0.1, should work on DSS 3.1.1) Also note you need to copy data source configuration properties if you have created carbon data sources therefore copy master-datasources.xml from repository/conf/datasources to the new installation.
Also Copy all the content of repository/component/lib  to the new installation to ensure the the jdbc drivers are properly installed.

Step 2- Change the configuration files

Apply the same changes you have done to configurations files inside OLD_DSS/repository/conf to NEW_DSS/repository/conf (if you have done any such to any configuration files)
Note - If you have done registry mounting make sure you apply to the new installation as done before by changing relevant configuration files such as
carbon.xml,axis2.xml,user-mgt.xml,mgt-transports.xml